# how to get X and Y coordinate from GPS on Windows-Mobile 6.1?

Tags: windows-mobile, gps

how to get  X  and  Y coordinate from GPS on Windows-Mobile 6.1  ?

can i get any sample code for this ?

thank's for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the GpsSample at the SDK. In 6.0 SDK it is located at

> "Windows Mobile 6
>   SDK\Samples\PocketPC\CS\GPS\GpsSample"

Answer (score 2):

Normally you'll need to make a software connection to the port which is connected to your GPS receiver . The receiver will send back [NMEA](http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm) strings which you need to read out as they come.

These can then be parsed to obtain that latitude and longitude reported by the reciever, check out [Writing your Own GPS Application](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/WritingGPSApplications1.aspx) for .NET.